# iterate through Json array and get nested object's value Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array with to access a list of properties which i have manage to get the value of these properties however, there is a nested object "**Region**" in the list which has a specific property "**regionName**" that i would like to retrieve the value, please check the code and uploaded images for reference.

I hope to this made sense. Thank You in advance

```
  export function CreateStores(xhttp: XMLHttpRequest, storeArray?: Array<PromotionClasses.Store>) {

    while (STORE_TABLE.rows.length > 1) {
        STORE_TABLE.deleteRow(1);
    }
    if (storeArray == undefined) {

        //Convert the response into an array of objects
        storeArray = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText) as Array<any>;
    }

   CheckForDuplicateStores(storeArray);



    //Get the current row length of the table so we know where to append to 
    let tableRowLength = STORE_TABLE.rows.length as number;
    console.log("Store array is");
 //   console.log(storesInPromotionArray);
    for (let i = 0; i < storeArray.length; i++) {

        //A dictionary containing the key value pair of the stores properties
        let tableData = {};




        //Add the store's id to the storeArray
        let store = new PromotionClasses.Store(storeArray[i]["StoreName"], storeArray[i]["id"]);

        storesInPromotionArray.push(store);
        console.log(storeArray[i]["region"]);
        var check = storeArray[i]["region"];




        //let attr = new PromotionClasses.Attribute(storeArray[i].name, storeArray[i].type, storeArray[i].property);
        //Assingattributes.push(attr);

        //Create and insert a new row

        let row = STORE_TABLE.insertRow(tableRowLength);
        //row.contentEditable = 'true'

        //The first three cells will always be the row number, store number and name
        tableData["#"] = i.toString();
        tableData["Number"] = storeArray[i]["storeNumber"];
        tableData["Name"] = storeArray[i]["storeName"];
        tableData["addressLine"] = storeArray[i]["addressLine"];
        tableData["postcode"] = storeArray[i]["postcode"];
        //****NESTED OBJECT PROPERTY = regionName
        tableData["region"] = storeArray[i]["region"];
```

[image: image example]

Comment: To access the property you can simply call `storeArray[i].region.regionName` - or `storeArray[i]["region"]["regionName"]`. But I am not sure if that was your question.

Comment: In both cases be aware, that this is not `null` save. E.g. when region is `null` there will be a null pointer exception.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Quali i have retrieve the data that i was after